# User Input from HTML form being cut off

Tags: php, html

We have an HTML form that takes in user input for an application, and uses PHP to process and send it to HR. The issue is it cutting off the text in the final result (picture below). There are no text limits set anywhere. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Parts being cut off:
[Cut Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLhbU.png)

The form declaration and code for the fields being cut off:

```
<form id="application" name="application" method="post" action="sendresults.php" align="left">

<p>Work Performed<br />
  <label>
    <textarea name="workperform1" id="workperform1" tabindex="62" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
  </label>
</p>
<p>Reason for Leaving<br />
    <label>
      <input name="reasonleaving1" type="text" onkeypress="return noenter()" id="reasonleaving1" tabindex="63"size="66" />
    </label>
      <br />
</p>
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php session_start(); 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Results</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php
            //--------------------------Set these paramaters--------------------------

            $subject = 'Application for Employment'; 

            $emailadd = 'blahblah@randomemail.org'; 

            // Where to redirect after form is processed. 
            $url = 'http://www.randomwebsitename/random.html'; 

            // Makes all fields required. If set to '1' no field can not be empty. If set to '0' any or all fields can be empty.
            $req = '0'; 

            // --------------------------Do not edit below this line--------------------------
            $text = "Results from form:\n\n"; 
            $space = ' ';
            $line = '
            ';
            
            include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';
            $securimage = new Securimage();
            
            
            if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
                die('The code you entered was incorrect.  Go back and try again.');
            }
            
            foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ){
            
                if ($req == '1'){
                        if( $value == '' ){
                        echo "$key is empty";
                        die;
                    }
                }
                $j = strlen($key);
                if( $j >= 20 ) {
                    echo "Name of form element $key cannot be longer than 20 characters";
                    die;
                }
                $j = 20 - $j;
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++){
                    $space .= ' ';
                }
                $value = str_replace('\n', "$line", $value);
                $conc = "{$key}:$space{$value}$line";
                $text .= $conc;
                $space = ' ';
            }
            
            mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: '.$emailadd.'');
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help you debug your code [Take a quick look at a coding standard for your own benefit](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). You may be asked to amend this code in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your tight crop eliminated all context, which makes it harder for us to understand what is going on. You've set explicit limits on both the `<textarea>` and the `<input>`. Are you saying the _values_ of those controls have been truncated? If you just mean that not all of the text is showing, then that is precisely what you told the browser to do.

Comment: Is that a screenshot of the form or some later report that is generated from the form values?

Comment: Yes, I agree the indenting isn't great, I recently started at this company and that will be something on my to-do list.

Comment: It is a screenshot of the report that is sent to our HR rep, generated from the form values.

Comment: Yes, I mean not all of the text is showing, but the limits put on there are fairly large, and it's cutting off after only 40, and 42 characters were typed, so I don't believe that could be the issue.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source of the report? Does it really contain a truncated value or it contains everything, just can't display it?

Comment: This is likely *just* a display issue caused by CSS or HTML. I copied/pasted your form and PHP and it isn't truncating any values. I'd start by looking at the report itself and its HTML/CSS to see if there are any styles being applied there which would cause this issue. You may even want to remove all CSS for now jusy to isolate the issue.

Comment: @El_Vanja I believe it's just a display issue. We run on an old Lotus Notes system (I know, yuck) and it's being sent to a subform there for the HR rep to view. I'm now assuming it's something within the design of that subform that's causing the issue. Strange thing is, there are other text box's on the subform set up the exact same way (copy/pasted actually) as the ones causing issues, yet they're functioning fine.